# Data collection. When to use an object over a form control?

Tags: c#

I come from a database background but am learning C#.
A lot of examples I see (especially when it comes to data collection) talk about creating objects with properties.
For example, entering a new employee you would create an instance of the employee class and set its properties such as name, title, salary etc.
This data would then be persisted in the back end database as a new record(s).

I'm wondering what the advantage of this is over, lets say, a data form that displays the fields to match DB columns, includes validation and logic checks to conform with business rules.

Is there a rule or a best practice as to when one is better than the other?
Ultimately the data will be sent to the database be it via collecting form values or object properties.

Comment: It's much easier to unit test business rules when they aren't tied to UI controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use both of these. You should have a class that sets the properties, the interface itself for entering data, and either the code-behind of the interface or a separate business layer that does validation checking on the data coming in.

The advantage is organization.  You have each class doing what it should, and only what it should.